# Gulp compiling with Babel gets Object.create error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs

I haven't found a solution for my problem, so I thought it is a bug and posted an Issue at gulp-babel's github repository. Link [here](https://github.com/babel/gulp-babel/issues/157).

But, maybe this is a better place to ask for help with these type of things. 
It is actually the first time I'm using gulp, so it may be easy to fix.

Here is the problem:
gulpfile.js:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const babel = require('gulp-babel');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('bundle', () => {
  return gulp
    .src([
      'src/js/definitions.js',
      'src/js/models/Object.js',
      'src/js/models/!(Object)*.js',
      'src/js/!(definitions)*.js'
    ])
    .pipe(babel({        // 
      presets: ['env']   // Problem is here
    }))                  // 
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1"
  "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1"
}
```

Error:
**Uncaught TypeError: Object.create is not a function at _inherits**

Cannot post images, since I have not enough reputation. Sorry.
Some of my classes inherits from another, that is the problem, but is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are getting the error at runtime, not compile time. Which node version are you using?

Comment: 8.11.1  I'll update it in a few minutes and inform about results.

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: Well, `Object.create` definitely exists in node. Can you clarify how/when/where the error happens?

Comment: Instantly, on page load.

Comment: *"Instantly, on page load."* So you are not executing the code in Node. You are executing it in some browser. So it seems the browser version you are using does not support `Object.create`.

Comment: Chrome 67.0.3396.99 Is it normal? How can I fix it?  
MDN says almost every browser supports that :|

Comment: Same thing in Firefox.

Comment: Are you overwriting `Object` or `Object.create` by any chance? `src/js/models/Object.js` sounds suspicious.

Comment: Damn... XDDDDDD

Comment: Yep it works now, sorry for your time XD